# draw two models in different positions opengl 2 android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm newbie with opengl2 in android, and I'm making an app in which I'm testing some things. Now I was trying to duplicate a sphere object with a texture, so I thought it was enough to change my MVP matrix applying a small translation to the Model matrix, using same View Matrix and same projection matrix.

```
    int[] numIndices = balon.getNumIndices();
    ShortBuffer[] indices = balon.getIndices();

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    for (int j = 0; j < numIndices.length; j++) {
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,
                numIndices[j], GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
                indices[j]);
    }

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix2, 0);
    for (int j = 0; j < numIndices.length; j++) {
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,
                numIndices[j], GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
                indices[j]);
    }
```

balon is an object of type Sphere. mMVPMatrix and mMVPMatrix2 are the MVP matrices I was talking about. I simply changed the MVP matrix and did the drawing again.
The result is that I have the two spheres, but one of them is behaving strangely, appears distorted, the position in which appears is right, the two spheres move along, but one of them changes it's shape.

What I'm missing?, I guess I have to duplicate some things in my code before I do this, but what?, thought that being the same model, this was enough...

This is how I changed the MVP matrix:

```
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix2, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, posX, posY, posZ);
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix2, 0, posX+0.5f, posY+0.5f, posZ);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix2, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix2, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix2, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix2, 0);
```

Comment: How DID you change mMVPMatrix2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloning mModelMatrix2 into mTempMatrix2 and using that as the operand in Matrix.multiplyMM instead of directly using mModelMatrix2, solved the problem

```
float[] mTempMatrix2 = mModelMatrix2.clone();
Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelMatrix2, 0, mTempMatrix2, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
```